# Bash function returns an unexpected value

Tags: bash, function, shell

I wrote this function in BASH, and it returns an unexpected value:

```
checkIfUserFound()
{
   isUserFound=$( cat user_uid.txt | grep $ADMIN_TO_UPDATE -B 1 | grep "uid" )
   return $isUserFound
}
```

the user_uid.txt file is empty (I enter invalid admin).

but for some reason, it returns "1":

```
checkIfUserFound
isUserFound=$?

if [ "$isUserFound" -eq "0" ];
then
    echo "Searching..."
else
    echo "User found..."
fi
```

This prints "User found..."

Does anyone know how come that is the returning value ? Shouldn't I get "0" when returning from the function ?

Comment: I recommend you [read the `grep` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html), especially about its [*exit code*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html#EXIT_STATUS).

Comment: Oh! I thought it returns the found string...

Comment: Hmmm how come, then, that if the file is not empty I get the error : "numeric argument required" ?

Comment: in "return $isUserFound

Comment: Neither a shell function or any program you run is like a mathematical function. They can *output* strings, and they can return an integer exit code. They cannot return arbitrary values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `return` needs to be a number (a small integer -- the range is 0 through 255).  But `grep` already sets its return code to indicate whether it found a match, and functions already return the return code of the last command in the function; so all you really need is

```
checkIfUserFound()
{
    grep "$ADMIN_TO_UPDATE" -B 1 user_uid.txt |
    grep -q "uid"
}
```

(Notice also how we get rid of the [useless use of `cat`).](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

The script could probably usefully be refactored to Awk.  Perhaps I am guessing correctly what you want:

```
checkIfUserFound()
{
    awk -v user="$ADMIN_TO_UPDATE" '/uid/ { p=1; next }
    p { if ($0 ~ user) found=1; p=0 }
    END { exit 1-found }' user_uid.txt
}
```

Finally, the code which calls this function should check whether it succeeded, not whether it printed 0.

```
if ! checkIfUserFound
then
    echo "Searching..."
else
    echo "User found..."
fi
```

Notice perhaps that `[` is not part of the `if` command's syntax (though `[` is one of the commands whose result code `if` is often used to check).

Comment: I want the function to know if grep returned empty or not, basically

Comment: And do you find that this does something else than that?

Comment: I am rather new to this. What you wrote returns 1 if found and 0 otherwise, right ? I will test it now

Comment: This returns "true" even for admins that do not exist

Comment: The one with "awk"

Comment: Then I guessed wrong what exactly your `grep` is supposed to do. Can you explain what the input file looks like and what the pattern is that you are looking for? (Using a file format which is a single line per record would make this a lot easier to handle with `grep` alone.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187486/discussion-between-mathenthusiast-and-tripleee).

Comment: I MSGed you in chat @tripleee

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you don't check for failure of any of the commands in the pipe.

The failure (exit code) of the last command in the pipe will be the exit value of the whole pipe. That exit code is available in the `$?` variable.

And since you want to return the success/failure of the pipe from the function, that's the value you need to return:

```
return $?
```

---

If the pipe doesn't fail then the result of the pipe will be the output on `stdout`, which will be put into the `$isUserFound` variable. Since it will not be a valid exit code (which must be numeric) then it can't be returned.

---

Since you don't need the `$isUserFound` variable, and you want to return the result of the pipe, your function could be simplified as

```
checkIfUserFound() {
   cat user_uid.txt | grep $ADMIN_TO_UPDATE -B 1 | grep "uid" 2>&1 >/dev/null
}
```

Comment: As per my answer just now, `return $?` is really superfluous; a function already returns the result code from the latest command.

Comment: How can I return what grep finds? I want to know if it returned empty string or not

Comment: `grep` sets its return code to 0 if it finds a match, 1 otherwise (or more generally nonzero in case of a failure)